# Error on trying to use python and mysql in xampp

Tags: python, mysql, xampp

I got python to print "hello world" on a web page
But just importing MySQL throws an error.

```
#!C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe
import mysql.connector
```

That's all the code in this file and it does this.

[image of the xampp page in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uavqj.png)

And I get a big error, with red text in cmd on...

> pip install MySQL-python

I Installed Microsoft dev tools 14, or whatever,
still errors,  and "import pymysql" gives the same error screen in firefox as "import mysql.connector".

Any ideas? I'm running windows 7.

---

Update -- I tried to install from the link in the comments dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python thanks @Tom Shaw.

Discovered Iv been running python 32 bit this whole time. Uninstalled python and got 64 bit as the only one on my computer now.  I still get the same error message viewing the page with firefox, and I was hoping pip install MySQL-python would work now, it still does not.  Until I can figure this out, I'm just going to use PHP for this project.

[image of pip install MySQL-python error in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnJd1.png)

Comment: Try import 

mysql.connector as mysql 

db = mysql.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "dbms"
)

print(db)

Comment: Make sure you download the connector. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/